# How to get VCard Property "Name" with ezvcard

Tags: vcf-vcard

I'm trying to get the "Name" of VCard properties, but I don't see a
"getName()" function. However, the following seems to work. Is it
legitimate to rely upon?

```
for (VCardProperty property : vCardThis.getProperties()){
  String propKeyS = property.toString() ;
  int atLoc = propKeyS.indexOf("@") ;
  String propName = propKeyS.substring(0, atLoc) ;
  System.out.println(propName) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name that is assigned to the property when it is serialized is stored in the property's **scribe** class.

To get a property's scribe class, use the `ScribeIndex` class like so:

```
ScribeIndex index = new ScribeIndex();
for (VCardProperty property : vCardThis.getProperties()){
  VCardPropertyScribe<? extends VCardProperty> scribe = index.getPropertyScribe(property);
  System.out.println(scribe.getPropertyName());
}
```